# What assembly language is this written in?

Tags: assembly

a. An early generation:

```
C7060F000055       mov     dword ptr [esi],5500000Fh
C746048BEC5151     mov     dword ptr [esi+0004],5151EC8Bh
```

b. And one of its later generations:

```
BF0F000055         mov     edi,5500000Fh
893E               mov     [esi],edi
5F                 pop     edi
52                 push    edx
B640               mov     dh,40
BA8BEC5151         mov     edx,5151EC8Bh
53                 push    ebx
8BDA               mov     ebx,edx
895E04             mov     [esi+0004],ebx
```

c. And yet another generation with recalculated ("encrypted") "constant" data:

```
BB0F000055         mov     ebx,5500000Fh
891E               mov     [esi],ebx
5B                 pop     ebx
51                 push    ecx
B9CB00C05F         mov     ecx,5FC000CBh
81C1C0EB91F1       add     ecx,F191EBC0h ; ecx=5151EC8Bh
894E04             mov     [esi+0004],ecx
```

Comment: Let me guess: this is part of a polymorphic engine.

Comment: @ninjalj nope. Metamorphic. Though recognizing it just by reading the assembly you must have experience in it yourself.

Comment: @Celeritas Why do you need an answer to this question? I'm not sure what practical application it would have. (Is it a rhetorical question, or does it have a purpose of some kind?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's x86 code in Intel (as opposed to AT&T) format. The fact that it's using registers like `ecx` means it's one of the 32-bit or better varieties.

The hex digits on the left are the machine language representation of the assembly language opcodes and operands on the rest of the line.

Comment: Beat me to it. This also looks like one of those job adverts for spooks ...

Comment: @Orwell, hence my "or better" modifier :-)

Comment: If the assumption that the addresses to the left are the memory addresses of the instructions is correct, this might be AMD64 stuff.

Comment: @Orwell the numbers on the left are not addresses those are the assembled instructions (machine code)